# What algorithm can I use to build a survey?

Tags: algorithm

I would like to learn about what algorithms, data structure to use for building a survey that can skip questions based on previous answers. A key requirement is the algorithm has to allow a question node can have multiple entry (like below, question 5 can be jumped to from question 1 or question 3). Also, this algorithm should allow insertion of another question (insert new question between 3 and 4)

For example

1. Are you male? (If yes,skip to 5).
2. How old are you?
3. Do you have a history of...? (If yes, skip to 5).
4. Do you live near...?
5. Do you experience ...?
6. ...

Comment: Builded a directed graph between the questions?

Comment: A directed ACYCLIC graph, that is...

Comment: and its not really a algorithm, its a data structure.

Comment: And a well chosen data structure is the backbone of any algorithm

Comment: A Bayesian network would be a good choice...Bayes nets are DAGs and offer flexibility in soft decision making (vs. the yes/no of typical rule engines)

Comment: This is not data mining (=analysis!). I removed the tag.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is a graph. Each graph edge would have a traversal condition.

Answer (score 0):

You need a tree-like structure. Here is the simple class that describe arbitrary node in this tree:

```
class Question {
   String questionText;
   List<String> possibleAnswers;
   int answer;
   List<Question> childQuestions;
}
```

At the beginning you show the `questionText` to user and list of possible answers. When user selects the answer, you retain the result in `answer` variable. And then, based on this variable, you select the next question from `childQuestions` list.

The one limitation on this solution: you have to define statically this tree.